# Why clone method is allowed on Array?

Tags: java, clone

`clone()` method is not visible by default in `Object` class so how does it does not give error for Array types?
Does this means that there is a type called int[] of which implementation is written in java and if yes where to find it ?
and if it is written then why not write it completely?
I mean why not implement every method properly not just the behaviour from `Object` Class.

```
    int[] a ={1,2,3};
    Object object = new Object();
    object.clone();//Does not compile since clone is protected.
    a.clone();// allowed as this method is from int[]
```

Comment: [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) - All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array and [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960574/do-we-inherit-from-object)

Comment: @AVD `clone` is `protected` in Object. `clone` is public in arrays. You did not answer that.

Answer (score 6):

All arrays implement the Cloneable interface.

See the relevant part of the Java Language Specification: [§10.7 Array Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)

> The public method `clone`, which overrides the method of the same name in class `Object` and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the `clone` method of an array type `T[]` is `T[]`.
>   A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.

Comment: I also wanted to know where is that implementation? And if Java has implemented `clone()` method for `Arrays` why not implement `equals()` method which will check of elements like `ArrayList`.

Comment: You probably can find the implementation in the source code.

equals() is implemented for Arrays as part of the Arrays class methods
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28boolean[],%20boolean[]%29

Comment: still weird that they decided to override clone() but not equals(), no?

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's a Cloneable interface that makes it so the `Object.clone()` method is accessible. Arrays in Java already implement Cloneable, so you can clone an array object.

An arbitrary Object on the otherhand, cannot guarantee that it can make a field-for-field copy of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays cannot be extended as normal objects. The only way to make an array `Cloneable` was to implement `Cloneable` interface from the start. For the same reason an array implements by default `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

An array is implemented as an instance of a dynamically created class by the JVM. That class has a special name and it implements the Cloneable and Serializable interfaces as noted by other posters above. (It also has a public final field named length...).

That class also has a concrete and **public** implementation of the protected Object.clone() method. Java allows the access level of a method (*public, private, protected & the default package-protected access levels*) to be made less restrictive when that method is overridden. In other words, a protected method can be made public in a subclass and that is what the JVM does with the protected clone() method for the array class implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Its because `clone()` is protected in `Object` class and protected access specifier says you can access the superclass protected method in the subclass of the same package. By this reasoning, `Object` class is in `java.lang` package and you are accessing it from a different package and that's why you are getting compilation error.