# can variables call methods in java language

Tags: java

my question is:
Can variables in java call method like this example:

```
private void test(Rabbit rabbit, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data) {

    byte[] crypt = rabbit.crypt(data.clone());}
```

as i know, data is a variable and it calls clone() method.
does data variable or no.

Comment: There are two types in java: primitive types and reference types. You can only invoke methods on variables of reference types.

Answer (score 1):

In this example data can call method clone, because data is object of byte[] class which is created by JVM, as it is a object can call clone method.

Answer (score 0):

Your real question here seems to be whether Java array objects support a `.clone()` method.

The answer is yes. All Java arrays implement `Cloneable`, and thus the `.clone()` method will work properly. See [Why clone method is allowed on Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086115/why-clone-method-is-allowed-on-array).

Note that this will be a "shallow" clone. That doesn't matter for primitives, but for Objects it means that the clone will contain references to the same objects as the original, not clones of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here data type of `data` variable is a Array. In Java Array is treated as  type of Object. Thus you can use `data.length` and `data.clone()` as valid statements.

`length` is a variable(of type `int`) in **`Array`** object and **`clone()`** is the method of **`Object`** class(Which is the super class of all classes in Java)

Answer (score 0):

Well...you're looking at the wrong symbol.  The short answer is, "it depends."

In Java, there are two types of things:

- **primitives**, which only hold a raw numerical value (in the case of `char`, often capable of being printed out),  and
- **objects**, which can not only hold values, but also perform method calls and access instance information.

`data` is actually a `byte[]`, and array types are special in that they [are an `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html), but not the instance of a class.  That said, there are a few things that it has - `clone()`, since [arrays implement `Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7), and all of the methods that are found on `Object`, which it inherits from.

In essence, you can call methods only on objects, but not primitives.