# Java Object be super of my class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I'm new on Java, reading the Sun basic tutorial and see "The Object class, defined in the java.lang package, defines and implements behavior common to all classes—including the ones that you write. " I wonder how can Object be the root parent of the class I defined if my class did not inherit from other classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960574/do-we-inherit-from-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the "magic" done by the Java compiler: when you write

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

Java compiler sees it as

```
public class MyClass extends java.lang.Object {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you continued reading on the [same page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) 
(emphasis mine):

> Excepting `Object`, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). **In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of `Object`**.

Answer (score 4):

This is an implicit behavior. All of your classes extend Object (directly or not).

`public class MyClass` is equivalent to `public class Myclass extends Object`

Answer (score 1):

It works that way because the [Java Language Specification (specifically section 8.1.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) says so:

> Given a (possibly generic) class declaration for C<F<sub>1</sub>,...,F<sub>n</sub>> (n ≥ 0, C ≠ Object), the direct superclass of the class type C<F<sub>1</sub>,...,F<sub>n</sub>> is the type given in the `extends` clause of the declaration of C if an extends clause is present, or `Object` otherwise.